# Cambiar color de texto de un Entry() desactivado

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Estaba descubriendo un poco más de tkinter y da que, haciendo un *Entry*, quería que estuviese desactivado pero con el texto de un color determinado.

Lo he intentado con el atributo `fg=` pero no funciona. Me he intentado informar sobre cómo hacerlo pero no encuentro nada.

Answer (score 2):

Para controlar el color del texto y del fondo tienes cuatro atributos a tu disposición:

- **`background`** o **`bg`**: Color de fondo cuando del entry cuando en estado normal. Por defecto es gris claro.
- **`foreground`** o **`fg`**: Color de primer plano (texto) cuando el widget está en estado normal. Por defecto es negro.
- **`disabledbackground`**: Color de fondo a mostrar cuando el widget está deshabilitado.
- **`disabledforeground`**: Color de primer plano (texto) cuando el widget está desactivado.

Por lo tanto debes usar el atributo `disabledforeground` cuando instancias tu `Entry` (o vía método `config`) para especificar el color de la fuente cuando esté desactivado.

Un pequeño ejemplo:

```
import tkinter as tk



class TestApp(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)
        self.parent = parent
        self.enabled_var = tk.IntVar(value=1)
        self.entry_text = tk.StringVar(value="Hola StackOverflow")

        self.entry = tk.Entry(self,
                              background="#ccff66",
                              foreground="#000000",
                              disabledbackground="#4d4d4d",
                              disabledforeground="#ffffff",
                              textvariable=self.entry_text 
                              )
        
        self.check_btn = tk.Checkbutton(self,
                                        text= "Enabled",
                                        variable=self.enabled_var,
                                        onvalue = 1,
                                        offvalue = 0,
                                        height=5,
                                        width=20,
                                        command=self.set_entry_state)
        
        self.entry.pack(side=tk.LEFT, expand=True, fill="x")
        self.check_btn.pack(side=tk.LEFT)


    def set_entry_state(self):
        if self.enabled_var.get():
            self.entry.configure(state=tk.NORMAL)
        else:
            self.entry.configure(state=tk.DISABLED)
               
        
        
        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    TestApp(root).pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
    root.mainloop()
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En el siguiente enlace tienes la documentación completa del widget `Entry` (en inglés):

http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/entry.html